# Calculating average of columns of singleparts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, average, mean

I have singleparts (pipes) with name and depth. I need to count the average depth based on name. So for e.g. pipe *'cont500str1'* has average depth `(2,93+2,03+1,99+1,17+2,12)/5 = 2,048`.

The complication is that some singleparts have the same name. So e.g. the first pipe *'plastic200'* has average depth `'(2,76+1,58)/2 = 2,17'`, second pipe *'plastic200'* has average depth `'(1,16+1,35+2,00+1,07+1,20)/5 = 1,356'`.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: You need unique IDs for your groups, otherwise this wont work.

Comment: If I create unique ID for groups, how to count average based on groups then? I tried "aggregate" function, but it doesnt work.

Comment: thank you, it works.

Answer (score 3):

As the first step you need to create a field containing a unique ID for each group. Once you got that, look at the "family" of `aggregate` expressions in the field calculator.

The specialized expression [`mean()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#mean) does exactly what you want: I gives you the mean of a column, if desired grouped by another column or expression, and if necessary also filtered.

In your case the expression would be `mean("your depth field","your group ID field")` - this gives you for each unique group ID the mean.

If you had `NULL` values in your depth field, you could filter them out adding `"your depth field" NOT LIKE NULL` as third parameter of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Groupstats plugin:
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/

Use the name column as Row, and the value that you want to aggregate with the mean function. The interface is similar to the Excel Pivot table.